# Is the following limit true or not? (function convergence)

Tags: analysis

Let $x\in(0,1)$, let $p>1.$ I was wondering if $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{2}{p}}x^{\frac{n}{p}}=0$ is true or not? I plotted some values and it seems to be true but I am struggling to prove this. Intuitively, one thing I can think of is that $x^{\frac{n}{p}}$ decays much quicker than $n^{\frac{2}{p}}$.

Comment: Note I made a small mistake in my original answer where I used l’Hôpital’s rule twice in the denominator. I first wrote it as being $n(n-1)y^{n-2}$ where, since I was differentiating wrt $n$ and not $y$, it should have been $(\ln(y))^2y^n$. This doesn't change the result, but I wanted to make sure you were aware in case you were using what I originally wrote.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you John! Classic error, I didn't spot it first time I read it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition

> that $x^{\frac{n}{p}}$ decays much quicker than $n^{\frac{2}{p}}$.

is basically correct. In general, exponential values of the form $y^z$ where $y \gt 1$, with $z \to \infty$, always eventually grow faster than any polynomials $p(z)$.

Since $x\in(0,1)$, then

$$y = \frac{1}{x} \gt 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As such, you can rewrite your limit as follows

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\frac{2}{p}}x^{\frac{n}{p}} & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\frac{2}{p}}}{y^{\frac{n}{p}}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^{2}}{y^{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \\
& = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{y^{n}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since you have the limits are $\infty$ in both the numerator & denominator, you can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). Using it twice gives

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{y^{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{(\ln(y))^2 y^{n}} = 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This shows the limit in \eqref{eq2A} is also $0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{\frac{2}{p}}x^{\frac{n}{p}} &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2}{p}\ln n}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{n}{p}\ln x}  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2 \ln n + n \ln x}{p}}
\end{align*}

Since $0<x<1$, $\ln x < 0$, so $n \ln x$ is a function linear in $n$ with negative slope.  $2 \ln n$ is logarithmic in $n$.  As you observe, the linear function dominates, so

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2 \ln n + n \ln x}{p}} &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{n \ln x}{p}}  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{\frac{n }{p}}  \\
    &= 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}